# How to stop adding numbers that occur twice in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, math

So I am trying to find an answer to the question:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I am using C# and have a pretty good idea of what to do, but my code keeps counting the numbers that occur twice (e.g. 15, 30) and I would like to know the quickest/easiest way to counteract that. everything I have found so far has been in a different language so I am sorry if this seems relatively easy to you. This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result1 = 0;
        var result2 = 0;
        var result3 = 0;
        var uniqueInts3 = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3)
        {
            uniqueInts3.Add(i);
            result1 += i;
        }
        var uniqueInts5 = new List<int>();
        for (var o = 0; o < 1000; o += 5)
        {
            uniqueInts5.Add(o);
            result2 += o;
        }
        result3 += result1 + result2;
        Console.WriteLine(result3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I would love if someone could explain to me what to do as I am not sure at this point.

Comment: What if you add all the ints in the same result and then remove duplicates and then sum them?

Comment: As a very side comment, if you plan to check for duplicates while generating a list, then use `HashSet<>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the most efficient way, but should work

```
var sum = 0;

for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   if(i%3==0||i%5==0) //checks if something is multiple of 3 or 5
      sum+=i; // sums only when it's multiple of 3 or 5
}
```

It ommits situations where something is multiple of 3 and 5. Takes each number once.

One line linq way:

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(3, 1000).Sum(x => (x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) ? x : 0);
```

Fastest mathematical approach version:

```
var result = SumDivisbleBy(3,999)+SumDivisbleBy(5,999)-SumDivisbleBy(15,999);

private int SumDivisbleBy(int n, int p)
{
    return n*(p/n)*((p/n)+1)/2;
}
```

it calculates sum of all numbers divisible by 3 and 5 then substracts sum of numbers divisible by 15. Explanation: http://www.wikihow.com/Sum-the-Integers-from-1-to-N

Comment: The O(1) solution has to be the winner. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, but your observation is also impressive :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
          .Where(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
          .Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are my 2 cents

Version 1, using a for loop.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (new[] {3, 5}.Any(n => i % n == 0)) 
        sum += i;
```

Version 2, using C# Linq

```
var sum =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10 - 1)
       .Where(e => new[] { 3, 5 }.Any(n => e % n == 0))
       .Sum();
```

`Enumerable.Range(1, 10 - 1)` creates a sequence of integers from 0 to 9 (less than 10).

`.Where(..)` is a method that filters the original sequence.

`new[] {3, 5}` creates another sequence containing only 3 and 5.

`.Any(n => e % n == 0)` takes 3 and 5 and the [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is performed on each number in the original sequence. Where the result is 0, the `Any` method returns true which in turn means that the `Where` method includes the number in the result.

And in the end there is the sum.

Comment: request is for 1000 range not 10 :) I think that using array here (`new[] { 3, 5 }`) is a little bit overkill (just my opinion) :)

Comment: What I am trying to prove with using the array is that you can use it as an input parameter without altering the algorithm. And for the 10/1000 thing, come on man :)

Comment: 10/1000 <-- just saying ;] ok, array thing is usefull here, sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide an alternative approach...

Firstly, we can observe that the multiples of 3 and 5 have gaps between them in the following repeating sequence:

```
2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3
```

Given that, we can write a method which computes the total like so:

```
int sumMultiplesOf3And5UpTo(int n)
{
    int i = 3;
    int j = 0;
    int t = 0;

    int[] increments = new []{2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3};

    while (i <= n)
    {
        t += i;
        i += increments[j++%7];
    }

    return t;
}
```

For ultimate speed, you can "unroll the increment array" like so:

```
int sumMultiplesOf3And5UpTo(int n)
{
    int i = 3;
    int t = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        t += i;
        i += 2;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 1;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 3;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 1;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 2;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 3;
        if (i > n) break;

        t += i;
        i += 3;
        if (i > n) break;
    }

    return t;
}
```

I would never really implement it like this; it's just a curiosity (and an example of a different approach).

Comment: Nice! [spacespacespace]

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is just loop all the numbers from 1 to 1,000 and see if they are multiplies of 3 or 5, if they are, just add them to a `result` variable outside the loop. As this is a project euler question, I'll let you figure the code by yourself. Good luck!

P.S., check out the [% operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx), it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the result before WriteLine()

`var sum = uniqueInts3.Concat(uniqueInts5).Distinct().Sum()`

Answer (score 1):

I played a little around and that's my solution:

```
private static int sumMultiples(int max, int small, int big)
{
    int sum = 0;

    int diff_add = big - small;
    int diff = diff_add;
    int next = small;
    while (next < max)
    {
        sum += next;

        if (next + diff < max
            && (next + diff) % small != 0)
        {
            sum += next + diff;
        }
        diff += diff_add;

        next += small;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The while-loop runs max/small times.